# Start an Orchestration if an other Orchestration gets a specific value

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I would like to do a main orchestration that receive a specific message and with a specific value in this message the main orchestration can call another orchestration (with call orchestration shape) that receive a different message with receive shape and do other function

Note: the main orchestration and the other orchestration is in the same project 
in general how can I proceed with 2 orchestration with a receive shape in each one

Answer (score 0):

I think you are heading toward the wrong direction, what you can do is like this.

1. Create a main orchestration,and receive the message (your specific) from message box.
2. In your orchestration, check the value you want to check.
3. When it is necessary to pass the message to another orchestration, you don't call the orchestration direction.  create a new message, use a map, to transfer the message you got to the message which another orchestration is listening.
4. Publish the message back to message box.

In this way, you don't need to call the orchestration directly. BizTalk will help you to schedule and passed message to the orchestration that you want to invoke.

Or you can use a message only solution, which means , you don't need to have a main orchestration at all, you can setup filters on your receive location, and then use map to transfer the message.